# non-www http version has two redirects in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I have a short issue of one of my sites.
I checked all redirects with httpstatus.io
All redirects are working without any issues, the only one which causes problem is the non-www http version of the site.

It first redirects to https non-www then to https www. I am trying to fix it since days but did not work. Is it bad for google?
I am using cloudflare SSL and this are my first lines in htaccess file:

```
 # BEGIN WpFastestCache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.my-domain.net
# Start WPFC Exclude
# End WPFC Exclude
# Start_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
```

after that i have this lines

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wordpress_logged_in_[^\=]+\=admin
# End_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www.my-domain.net
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(facebookexternalhit|LinkedInBot|WhatsApp|Mediatoolkitbot)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(WP\sFastest\sCache\sPreload(\siPhone\sMobile)?\s*Bot)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
```

hope you can help

---

```
# BEGIN WpFastestCache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.my-domain.net
# Start WPFC Exclude
# End WPFC Exclude
# Start_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wordpress_logged_in_[^\=]+\=admin
# End_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www.my-domain.net
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(facebookexternalhit|LinkedInBot|WhatsApp|Mediatoolkitbot)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(WP\sFastest\sCache\sPreload(\siPhone\sMobile)?\s*Bot)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\/){2}$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wordpress_logged_in
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !comment_author_
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !woocommerce_items_in_cart
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !safirmobilswitcher=mobil
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*(\bCrMo\b|CriOS|Android.*Chrome\/[.0-9]*\s(Mobile)?|\bDolfin\b|Opera.*Mini|Opera.*Mobi|Android.*Opera|Mobile.*OPR\/[0-9.]+|Coast\/[0-9.]+|Skyfire|Mobile\sSafari\/[.0-9]*\sEdge|IEMobile|MSIEMobile|fennec|firefox.*maemo|(Mobile|Tablet).*Firefox|Firefox.*Mobile|FxiOS|bolt|teashark|Blazer|Version.*Mobile.*Safari|Safari.*Mobile|MobileSafari|Tizen|UC.*Browser|UCWEB|baiduboxapp|baidubrowser|DiigoBrowser|Puffin|\bMercury\b|Obigo|NF-Browser|NokiaBrowser|OviBrowser|OneBrowser|TwonkyBeamBrowser|SEMC.*Browser|FlyFlow|Minimo|NetFront|Novarra-Vision|MQQBrowser|MicroMessenger|Android.*PaleMoon|Mobile.*PaleMoon|Android|blackberry|\bBB10\b|rim\stablet\sos|PalmOS|avantgo|blazer|elaine|hiptop|palm|plucker|xiino|Symbian|SymbOS|Series60|Series40|SYB-[0-9]+|\bS60\b|Windows\sCE.*(PPC|Smartphone|Mobile|[0-9]{3}x[0-9]{3})|Window\sMobile|Windows\sPhone\s[0-9.]+|WCE;|Windows\sPhone\s10.0|Windows\sPhone\s8.1|Windows\sPhone\s8.0|Windows\sPhone\sOS|XBLWP7|ZuneWP7|Windows\sNT\s6\.[23]\;\sARM\;|\biPhone.*Mobile|\biPod|\biPad|Apple-iPhone7C2|MeeGo|Maemo|J2ME\/|\bMIDP\b|\bCLDC\b|webOS|hpwOS|\bBada\b|BREW).*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f [or]
RewriteCond /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html" [L]
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "index\.(html|htm)$">
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Mon, 29 Oct 1923 20:30:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END WpFastestCache
# BEGIN GzipWpFastestCache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddType x-font/woff .woff
AddType x-font/ttf .ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype font/ttf font/eot font/otf
</IfModule>
# END GzipWpFastestCache
# BEGIN LBCWpFastestCache
<FilesMatch "\.(webm|ogg|mp4|ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|js|css|swf|x-html|css|xml|js|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot)(\.gz)?$">
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
AddType application/font-woff2 .woff2
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
ExpiresByType video/webm A2592000
ExpiresByType video/ogg A2592000
ExpiresByType video/mp4 A2592000
ExpiresByType image/webp A2592000
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/ico A2592000
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A2592000
ExpiresByType text/css A2592000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType application/javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A2592000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Expires "max-age=2592000, public"
Header unset ETag
Header set Connection keep-alive
FileETag None
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END LBCWpFastestCache
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: "I am trying to fix it since days but did not work. Is it bad for google?" - However, is there anything really to "fix" here? This isn't "bad for Google" and if you plan on implementing HSTS then this is actually a requirement. If you are using CloudFlare then you should probably be implementing _page rules_ anyway to handle the redirects.

Comment: You don't have any redirects at all in the `.htaccess` file you posted. (Is it supposed to?) It would seem your redirects are handled by something else (WordPress or Cloudflare). _Aside..._ Your `WpFastestCache` code block has 2 conditions that are mutually exclusive (ie. `%{HTTPS} =on` and `%{HTTPS} !=on` can't both be successful), so it's not going to do anything?